# Как работает декоратор внутри движка js

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю как работает декоратор внутри движка JS, в строке `slow = cachingDecorator(slow);`. Мы в `slow` возращаем анонимную функцию и функция `slow` перезаписывается этой анонимной функцией из замыкания, анониманая функция имеет доступ на внешнию область видимости где содержится коллекция `Map` и переданная функция `slow`, но `slow` мы уже перезаписали!

Почему остается ссылка на старую функцию `slow` или как она запоминает эту функцию в своей области видимости? То есть в строке `result = func(x)` мы вызываем функцию без изменений. Не понимаю! Мы же перезаписали эту функцию! Помогите пожалуйста!

```js
function slow(x) {
  // здесь могут быть ресурсоёмкие вычисления
  console.log(`Called with ${x}`);
  return x;
}

function cachingDecorator(func) {
  let cache = new Map();

  return function(x) {
    if (cache.has(x)) { // если кеш содержит такой x,
      return cache.get(x); // читаем из него результат
    }

    let result = func(x); // иначе, вызываем функцию

    cache.set(x, result); // и кешируем (запоминаем) результат
    return result;
  };
}

slow = cachingDecorator(slow);

console.log(slow(1)); // slow(1) кешируем
console.log("Again: " + slow(1)); // возвращаем из кеша

console.log(slow(2)); // slow(2) кешируем
console.log("Again: " + slow(2)); // возвращаем из кеша
```

Comment: Вам станет яснее если замените `slow = cachingDecorator(slow);` на `const cachedSlow = cachingDecorator(slow);` и потом будете вызывать его?

Comment: То есть запишем в новую переменную эту функцию?

Comment: Да, если вызов докоратора будет записан в другую переменную

Comment: С другой переменной понятно в этом случае мы не переписываем функцию slow,а просто возвращаем анонимную функцию в новую переменную,но там то мы переписываем функцию slow то есть возвращаем анонимную функцию в slow

Comment: Или вот это slow это новая переменная?Но мы же ее не объявили через let или const

Comment: Анонимная функция имеет доступ к функции `func` переданной аргументом. Она ничего не знает ни про какую внешнюю функцию `show`

Comment: То есть если мы передали функцию как аргумент то она навсегда запоминает эту функцию и держит ее в своей локальной области видимости пока другая функция ссылается на нее?и при любом внешнем изменении функции,анонимная функция все равно будет помнить только локальную функцию которую мы передали?

Comment: @EzioMercer, вы забыли упомянуть что запись в другую переменную даст неполное кеширование если функция рекурсивная. В этом примере это не важно, в других может попортить кровь.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я не могу нормально объяснить как работает без рекурсии, а вы хотите, чтобы я объяснял с рекурсиями)) Если у вас более простое и верное объяснение, то я бы почитал. В следующий раз уже ваш пример рассказывал бы)

Comment: @EzioMercer, я это объяснить не могу без углубления в тонкости работы компилятора. Кажется, тут вообще нет простого объяснения.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy И я пока не нашёл простых объяснений...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меня закидают помидорками за такое объяснение, но чтобы в целом поняли как это работает расскажу :)

Рассмотрим этот кусок:

```
function slow(x) {
  // здесь могут быть ресурсоёмкие вычисления
  console.log(`Called with ${x}`);
  return x;
}
```

Теперь представим себе что `slow` - это просто указатель на это блок (далее: `{*}`) :

```
{
  // здесь могут быть ресурсоёмкие вычисления
  console.log(`Called with ${x}`);
  return x;
}
```

и когда мы пишем `slow(value)`, то он просто приписывает в начало в этого блока `let x = value;` и выполняет этот блок

Теперь рассмотрим ф-ию:

```
function cachingDecorator(func) {
  ...
}
```

Не важно что и как он делает, главное мы знаем, что он умеет запоминать то что ему отправили в `func`, а `cachingDecorator` - так же возвращает указатель на свой блок (далее: `{**}`)

Когда мы пишем:

```
slow = cachingDecorator(slow);
```

мы ему (`cachingDecorator`) отправлем указатель на `{*}` и он его у себя хранит и получаем указатель на `{**}`, а он записвается в `slow`. Теперь когда мы напишем `slow(value)` он отправит `value` в блок `{**}` и выполнит его. Блок `{**}` в свою очередь выполнит блок `{*}`

В целом на этом всё :)

Comment: Так он запоминает копию этой функции когда мы ее передаем или ссылается на функцию slow?

Comment: @Hello Зря я кажется объяснил таким образом :) Скажем так, `slow` сама является ссылкой, потому на него никто не ссылается, все ссылаются на блоки

Comment: Объяснение плохо работает для рекурсивной `slow`. Надо как-то объяснить что ссылки на `slow` изнутри самой `slow` заменяются на блок `{**}`.

Comment: Но ссылка slow содержит блок {*}, Разве мы не перезаписываем ссылку на блок анонимной функции которую возвращаем

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я честно не знаю, как объяснить ещё проще перезаписывание ссылок)

Comment: @Hello, нет. Технически мы замещаем значение в имени `slow`. Все упоминания этого имени начинают ссылаться на новый блок.